# jquery autocomplete bring value and key

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

first at all thanks for reading.

I was reading a lot of similar post but really, i dont understand how to get it working.

Here's the thing, i have a jquery autocomplete that brings an array from a php that i used json_encode. Example of the array

array('23' => 'Robert','3' => 'alaric'... and so on.

The input that is completed by the autocomplete obviously bring me the Value of that array. 
But now what i need to do for other script is, in the input show the name (just the way its right now) but when i click at a button right next to that input (called it '+', "submit" buttono or  doesnt matter the type) to complete a select multiple empty that is at the right, i will need to put as value the key of the array and the text of the option the Value of the array...

so here's my code of autocomplete and my input, hope you can help me

```
<input type="text" name="letter" placeholder="Nombre Medico..." id="search_medico"/>


    $(function() {
            $("#search_medico").autocomplete({
              minLength: 3,
              source: '<?php echo $general->full_path?>view/general/search_medico.php'
            });
        });
```

and i need to complete a select like

her ei need to add each one option

Answer (score 0):

I don't get exactly what you want to do but to access value and label of a selected item in a jquery ui autocomplete, you can use the select event callback.

```
    $(function() {
        $("#search_medico").autocomplete({
          minLength: 3,
          source: '<?php echo $general->full_path?>view/general/search_medico.php',
          select : function(event, ui) {
                  // ui.item.label is the displayed value
                  // ui.item.value is the key
                  // you can here put these values somewhere else in your page
          }
        });
    });
```

**EDIT** :

Your source must be in this format :

[{value : 1977, label : "CARBALLO JACINTO"}, {value : 4527, label :  "CARBALLO GAIS NATALIA"}, ... ]

Comment: 1977: "CARBALLO JACINTO"
4527: "CARBALLO GAIS NATALIA"
5439: "CARBALLO NESTOR O"
8997: "CARBALLO VIVIANA"
10059: "CARBALLO QUIBEL LUIS RENE"
11111: "CARBALLO GRACIELA"
12863: "CARBIA CARLOS"
15005: "CARBALLIDO MARCELA ALEJANDRA"
17320: "CARBALLO MARTIN"
18520: "CARBALLIDO MARCELA"

That's my array in json and i need the 1977, but i think thatis not the label is more like key but nothing appear when ui.item.key :/(

when i used .value print the value of the array not the key as u wrote:(

Comment: your source is not in the right format for jquery autocomplete. Check the edit I made and read documentation here : http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: thank u very much, for your help i could finish it =).

Was the array format my problem as u said